# In list definition, can I use an else statement (for base case handling)?

Tags: python, list, definition, if-statement

what I'd like to do is something like:

```
sum([probabilities[ngram] for ngram in combination if probabilities.has_key(ngram)])
```

this part is just fine. What I'd like to do is make something which handles a 'base case', that is to say assumes a certain probability, say .0001,

```
if not probabilities.has_key(ngram): 
    sum([probabilities[ngram] for ngram in combination if probabilities.has_key(ngram) else .0001])
```

Where probabilities is a dict with ntuples as keys and floats as values, combination is a list of ntuples.

edit fixed some brackets

Comment: I fixed your formatting ('edit' your post to see what you need to do when you post code).  The `{}` button can be used to indent a hilighted block and make it display as code.

Answer (score 3):

No.

```
sum(probabilities.get(ngram, 0.0001) for ngram in combination)
```